# Numpy gradient on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I want to perform a numpy gradient on a pandas groupby object:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x_vars = ['x_val']
df = pd.DataFrame({'gr':['a','a','a','b','b','b', 'b'],
                  'e_time':[0,1,2,0,1,2,3],
                  'x_val':[1,2,3,0,1,4,9]})

gb = df.groupby('gr')

for v in x_vars:
    df[f'{v}_diff'] = gb[v].diff()  # OK
    df[f'{v}_pct'] = gb[v].pct_change()  # OK

display(df)
```

I've tried the following but without success:

```
for v in x_vars:
    df[f'{v}_grd'] = gb.apply(lambda gp:np.gradient(gp[v], gp['e_time']))  # NOK
```

Ideally I should have the same results as :

```
for v in x_vars:
    good_output={}
    for gn, gp in gb:
        good_output[gn] = np.gradient(gp[v], gp['e_time'] / 1)
    flat_list = [item for sublist in good_output.values() for item in sublist]
    df[f'{v}_grd'] = flat_list
```

But I get the feeling there is a more pythonic way to proceed.

NB : I want to be sure that `gr` and `e_time` are aligned in `df`

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to be working as I wanted:

```
for v in x_vars:
    df[f'{v}_grd'] = gb.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({f'{v}_grd': np.gradient(x[v], x['e_time'])},
                                                                  index=x.index))
display(df)
```

The trick was to add the DataFrame constructor into the `lambda` function.